# Setting from address in phpmailer webforms

Tags: php, webforms, phpmailer

I am using the following code to send emails using phpmailer 6:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'myhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = 'email@mydomain.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->Port = '587';

$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->setFrom('email@mydomain.com');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body    = "...";

$mail->send();
```

The email sends successfully to our company, however it always says it is from email@mydomain.com, which makes it hard for staff to find specific emails in their inbox.  In the form, the user provides their name and email so ideally I'd like it to appear in Outlook as being sent from John Doe (jdoe@gmail.com) rather than email@mydomain.com.

In old versions of webforms I use to do this by setting the from address however now that doesn't seem to be possible because it's considered spoofing.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add in the name as the second parameter in your `setFrom`. See the example below:

```
$mail->setFrom('darth@empire.com', 'Darth Vader');
```

It'll then appear as you want it!

Comment: Tried that.  It's still appearing as the name I set in the email@mydomain.com account.

Comment: This is the right way to do it, however, many email clients ignore it, especially if you have received other messages from that address before, and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks.  We are on Office 365 and I wondered if settings are preventing it from displaying.  I will use the setFrom code above in case it may work for some clients.

Comment: @user1480951 maybe checks their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/how-office-365-validates-the-from-address) and ensure the name is formatted correctly? Also check in the raw emails that office365 and see if the from name is intact and proper there. You could test sending messages to a gmail account and see if it's proper.